# .live checking for change on checkbox is not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox, jquery

I am trying to check if multiple checkboxes with the class "monitor" are changed.

Here is my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fogest/g4fY4/) and code below:

```
var serviceTracker = {};
$('.add-remove-new').live('click', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Remove') {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    if ($('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).hasClass('existing')) {
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()] = {};
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()].action = 'Delete';
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()].active = 0;
    }
    else {
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()] = {};
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()].action = 'Delete';
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()].active = 0;
    }
  }
  else if ($(this).val() == 'Add') {
    $('tr.newService:last').clone().insertAfter($('tr.newService:last'));
    $(this).val('Remove');
    serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()] = {};
    serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()].action = 'Add';
    serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()].active = 1;
  }
  console.log(serviceTracker);
});
$('.monitor').live('change', function() {
  if (typeof(serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()]) === 'undefined' && typeof(serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()]) === 'undefined') {
    if (typeof(serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()]) === 'undefined') serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()] = {};
    else serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()] = {};
  }
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    if (serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()] in serviceTracker) {
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()].active = 1;
    }
    else if (serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()] in serviceTracker) {
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()].active = 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()] in serviceTracker) {
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val()].active = 0;
    }
    else if (serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()] in serviceTracker) {
      serviceTracker[$('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).text()].active = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

I am getting no error, but nothing is happening. The expected result is that an object with the name of the Services is either created with the active variable being filled, or if it already exists then the active variable is simply changed.

*(Note: I am using version 1.6.1 of jquery, so I am unable to use on())*

Comment: Use .delegate instead of .live for older versions of jquery

Comment: You should definitely bind $(this).parent().parent(), or $('.service', $(this).parent().parent()).val() in variables for performance reasons...

Comment: @rlemon Can you explain why?

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf Probably is a good idea, I will make this change on the code.

Comment: @rlemon - that is kind of a weird statement, not saying it is wrong, but it is confusing and here is why: `live` actually predates (introduced jQuery 1.3) `delegate` (introduced jQuery 1.4), but the advice of using `delegate` over `live` is due to the fact that `live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7; so the term "older versions of jQuery" is relative to 1.7, but not earlier than 1.4.

Comment: "I am using an older version of jquery": which version specifically?

Comment: @cfs - in the jsfiddle provided it references jQuery 1.6

Comment: @cfs As Karl said, it is in the jsfiddle, but I should have included it here too. It is version 1.6.1, though the fiddle has 1.6.4 selected as there was no 1.6.1 option.

Comment: not an answer, but setting a var equal to parent parent jquery object would make this script way more efficient and way more readable.

Comment: @Rooster Do you have an example of how I should do this? I tried using  `var parent = $(this).parent().parent())` and then I used it like so: `parent.val()` and `parent.text()`. This did not work though, did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Fogest check this fiddle to see what I mean.  I only modded the remove functions.  http://jsfiddle.net/g4fY4/1/     I tried working on your problem, but I don't really understand what youre trying to do.  Your setting an array index as an entire table rows text content???

Comment: @Rooster The table data that you see in the sample fiddle need to be saved on form submission. Due to the way I have the yii framework setup on this page I am doing more of a workaround. I am not experienced enough to know how to do this via ajax so I thought it would be an okay idea to save it as essentially a 2D array, and then return this data to a hidden field as JSON.